# draggable div to stay in position when scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a menu which can be dragged around my page. 
I've made this menu which is draggable.

My problem is when I scroll down the page the menu doesn't stays and therefore the menu dissapears.

I've put the position attribute of the menu to "absolute" in order to make it draggable.

Is there any way to make the menu "fixed" when I scroll down the page or when I jump the page with a hyperlink.

note:
The menu consists of two divs. when you press "menu" you open up to different hyperlinks and you can thereby also jump the page with these hyperlinks.

Thank you fro your time

```css
#div_drag {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: actor;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a.color {
  color: white;
}

.test {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </link>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="div_drag">

    <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display='';return false;" href=""><br>menu</a>

    <div id="div_name2" style="display:none;position: absolute;z-index: 10;background-color: black;font-family:actor;text-align center;width:170px;height:170px;padding: 10px;cursor: move;top:-20px;left:-20px;">

      <a href="firstyear.html" class="color">+2018</a>
      <br></br>
      <a href="#1" class="color">1</a>
      <a href="#2" class="color">2</a>
      <a href="#3" class="color">3</a>
      <a href="secondyear.html" class="color">+2017</a>
      <br></br>
      <a href="thirdyear.html" class="color">+2016</a>
      <br></br>
      <a href="fourthyear.html" class="color">+2015</a>
      <br></br>

      <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display='none';return false;" href="">hide</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    dragElement(document.getElementById(("div_drag")));

    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0,
        pos2 = 0,
        pos3 = 0,
        pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }

      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
      }

      function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
  </script>


  <div class="test">
    <a name="1"></a>
    hello!
  </div>

  <div class="test">
    <a name="2"></a>
    hello!
  </div>

  <div class="test">
    <a name="3"></a>
    hello!
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You probably just need to change the div_drag position to 'fixed'. I've tested your code on jsfiddle and I think it's the result you're expecting: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/297610/

Answer (score 4):

Why not use position fixed?

```css
#div_drag {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: actor;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a.color {
  color: white;
}

.test {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet'>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </link>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="div_drag">

    <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display='';return false;" href=""><br>menu</a>

    <div id="div_name2" style="display:none;position: absolute;z-index: 10;background-color: black;font-family:actor;text-align center;width:170px;height:170px;padding: 10px;cursor: move;top:-20px;left:-20px;">

      <a href="firstyear.html" class="color">+2018</a>
      <br></br>
      <a href="#1" class="color">1</a>
      <a href="#2" class="color">2</a>
      <a href="#3" class="color">3</a>
      <a href="secondyear.html" class="color">+2017</a>
      <br></br>
      <a href="thirdyear.html" class="color">+2016</a>
      <br></br>
      <a href="fourthyear.html" class="color">+2015</a>
      <br></br>

      <a onclick="document.getElementById('div_name2').style.display='none';return false;" href="">hide</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    dragElement(document.getElementById(("div_drag")));

    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0,
        pos2 = 0,
        pos3 = 0,
        pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }

      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
      }

      function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
  </script>


  <div class="test">
    <a name="1"></a>
    hello!
  </div>

  <div class="test">
    <a name="2"></a>
    hello!
  </div>

  <div class="test">
    <a name="3"></a>
    hello!
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you that worked. I already tried it. Most have done something wrong the first time.

Comment: Perfect, glad to could help. Please mark this question as answered. Thx